# Pointing bash to a python installed on windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 and have Python installed. The new update brought bash to windows, but when I call python from inside bash, it refers to the Python installation which came with the bash, not to my Python installed on Windows. So, for example, I can't use the modules which I have already installed on Windows and would have to install them separately on the bash installation.

How can I (and can I?) make bash point to my original Windows Python installation? I see that in /usr/bin I have a lot of links with "python" inside their name, but I am unsure which ones to change, and if changing them to Windows directories would even work because of different executable formats.

Comment: The ability to run Windows programs from WSL is [on the backlog](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13284702-let-us-launch-windows-processes-from-bash).

Comment: I see now, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Windows 10 Insider build #14951, you can now invoke Windows executables from within Bash.

You can do this by explicitly calling the absolute path to an executable (e.g. `c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`), or by adding the executable's path to the bash path (if it isn't already), and just calling, for example, `notepad.exe`.

> Note: Be sure to append the `.exe` to the name of the executable - this is how Linux knows that you're invoking something foreign and routes the invocation request to the registered handler - WSL in this case.

So, in your case, if you've installed Python 2.7 on Windows at C:\, you might invoke it using a command like this from within bash:

`$ /mnt/c/Python2.7/bin/python.exe`

(or similar - check you have specified each folder/filename case correctly, etc.)

HTH.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". Just to be clear, this would run the windows installation of Python and not the WLS installation of Python, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Windows 10 installed, but I use Babun and I had the same problem. As I read aliases work well in Windows 10 shell so simply add alias in your .bashrc pointing to your Python installation directory:

```
alias python /mnt/c/Python27/python
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least four options:

1. Specify the complete absolute path to the python executable you want to use.
2. Define an alias in your .bashrc file
3. Modify the PATH variable in your .bashrc file to include the location of the python version you wish to use.
4. Create a symlink in a directory which is already in your PATH.

Comment: Currently the Linux subsystem can't launch a PE executable in the Windows subsystem. Apparently they are considering this, and it may (should) eventually be supported. I suppose it could be implemented in the `exec` family of system calls, or they could add a special "/bin/cmd" program that starts an instance of cmd.exe in Windows, just as bash.exe starts /bin/bash in Linux. Then one could run Windows Python via `cmd /c python ...`.

Comment: @eryksun I probably misread/misunderstood the original question. I didn't realize that the "bash" under discussion is actually part of Windows and not a third-party tool such as cygwin or mingw.

Comment: See [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about). This is a new subsystem in Windows 10 that runs Linux ELF binaries directly by mapping Linux system calls to NT system calls.

Comment: @Code-apprentice: You may want to delete your answer as none of your suggestions will currently work on Bash/WSL.