# BashOperator execute python installed on windows

Tags: python, bash, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Please reference:

[Pointing bash to a python installed on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794937/pointing-bash-to-a-python-installed-on-windows).

Taking that concept and attempting to apply to Apache Airflow. I have Airflow running on a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I also have a Python installation and .py file installed on Windows 10. I'd like to execute the .py file using Airflow.

If I execute the following in Ubuntu:

```
/mnt/c/path/to/windows_python/python.exe C:\\path\\to\\my\\python\\file\\my_file.py
```

my_file.py runs using my Windows 10 installation of Python. However if I make that same call using BashOperator in a DAG I see a "Bash command failed" error. The task in my DAG file looks like:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'my_task'
    , bash_command = '/mnt/c/path/to/windows_python/python.exe C:\\path\\to\\my\\python\\file\\my_file.py'
    , dag = dag)
```

The DAG fails in Airflow with the message in the logs: can't open file C:\path\to\my\python\file\my_file.py. No such file or directory.

The reason I want to call the Python file and executable on the Windows side is because I already have SQL drivers and VPN setup there.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Goal is to call .py file from Airflow (running on WSL) by any means necessary.

Comment: doest windows10 has bash command?   Or do you need install bash in the power shell environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here in case someone else needs this in the future. I can't explain the behavior I see but as a workaround:

1. Create .sh file containing the bash command
2. Call the .sh file using BashOperator

Example:

```
command = '/path/to/sh/file/my_file.sh '

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'my_task'
    , bash_command = command
    , dag = dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you place your Python files in dags folder the **BashOperator** executes the file. But when I try outside the dags folder I doesn't work. Seems you have to put the file inside dags folder or you can create another folder inside the dags folder and place your Python scripts there.